# Edit a document by running a macro on another document OR ignore the empty lines in an array?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to improve a macro that pulls data from a tab-separated docx file.

On the document I run the macro, it finds the words on the left (from the tab-separated file), replaces them with the words on the right.

I put together something that does what I need. However, if there's an empty line left at the end of the reference list, my macro gives

> Run-time Error 9, subscript out of range.

This can be solved by deleting that empty line but I'd like to make the macro work better and ignore that somehow.

I have two different fixes in mind.

1. When I run my macro, try to delete the empty lines from the reference list.
   How do I edit a document with a macro being run on another document?
2. Modify the loops, so instead of `UBound - 1 to 0` and `0 to Unbound - 1, they detect the lines with characters or they ignore empty lines.

```vb
Sub BulkFindReplace()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim FRDoc As Document, FRList, j As Long

'Load the strings from the reference doc into a text string to be used as an array.
Set FRDoc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\refList.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Addtorecentfiles:=False, Visible:=False)
FRList = FRDoc.Range.FormattedText
FRDoc.Close False
Set FRDoc = Nothing
    
If Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(0), vbTab)(0) > Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(0), vbTab)(1) Then
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = True
        'Process each word from the Check List. Tab-delimited strings are assumed, formatted as:
        'Find text <Tab> Replace text
        For j = 0 To UBound(Split(FRList, vbCr)) - 1
            .Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(j), vbTab)(0)
            .Replacement.Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(j), vbTab)(1)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
    End With
Else
    With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .MatchCase = True
        'Process each word from the Check List. Tab-delimited strings are assumed, formatted as:
        'Find text <Tab> Replace text
        For j = UBound(Split(FRList, vbCr)) - 1 To 0 Step -1
            .Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(j), vbTab)(0)
            .Replacement.Text = Split(Split(FRList, vbCr)(j), vbTab)(1)
            .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
        Next
    End With
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Example:

Word file to be processed:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

The list macro references (macro replaces the numbers on left with numbers on right)

```
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
```

Problem:
If the list has an empty line at the end like this (happens a lot when copying stuff, I want to foolproof this), macro gives an error:

```
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‎
```

‎Possible fix:

1. Edit the list in the macro to get rid of any empty lines. I know how to delete the empty lines but I don't know how to do that to another document (the list), while I'm running the macro from the main document.

Comment: Please add an example of the text you wish to process. Your explanation is not very clear.

Comment: Sorry. I tried to add a simpler explanation with examples at the end of my post with an edit. Is it better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If, as you assume, the empty line is a result of an empty paragraph at the end of your reflist.docx, your first line of defence is to make sure that you never leave an empty paragraph at the end of that document.

Your second line of defence is to ensure that you check the range you are building `FRList` from doesn't have an empty paragraph at the end, which is trivial to do.

Given that you have declared `FRList` as a variant (you omitted the datatype so it is automatically assigned the default of variant) you can also make your code cleaner, and easier to read, by assigning the array output by `Split` to `FRList`, as I have done below.

```
Sub BulkFindReplace()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim FRDoc As Document, FRRng As Range, FRList As Variant, j As Long

    'Load the strings from the reference doc into a text string to be used as an array.
    Set FRDoc = Documents.Open("C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\refList.docx", ReadOnly:=True, Addtorecentfiles:=False, Visible:=False)
    FRRng = FRDoc.Range.FormattedText
    If Len(FRRng.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Text) = 1 Then FRRng.MoveEnd wdCharacter, -1
    FRList = Split(FRRng, vbCr)
    FRDoc.Close False
    Set FRDoc = Nothing
    If Split(FRList, vbTab)(0) > Split(FRList, vbTab)(1) Then
        With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = True
            'Process each word from the Check List. Tab-delimited strings are assumed, formatted as:
            'Find text <Tab> Replace text
            For j = 0 To UBound(FRList) - 1
                .Text = Split(FRList(j), vbTab)(0)
                .Replacement.Text = Split(FRList(j), vbTab)(1)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next
        End With
    Else
        With ActiveDocument.Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchCase = True
            'Process each word from the Check List. Tab-delimited strings are assumed, formatted as:
            'Find text <Tab> Replace text
            For j = UBound(FRList) - 1 To 0 Step -1
                .Text = Split(FRList(j), vbTab)(0)
                .Replacement.Text = Split(FRList(j), vbTab)(1)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
            Next
        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Making a condition based on line length (if I'm understanding your fix correctly...) never occured to me. That's super cool to learn. And thank you for going out of your way to make the code way cleaner as well, much appreciated!